# Sending content of a file in one email ()

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am a simple program reading content of a file and if certain names are found, I need to email out only those words.  The email part is sending individual emails at each iteration instead of combining all in one.

```
Chokeberry
Hawthorn
Loquat
Medlar
Pear
```

This is part of the code

```
file="/home/rkelly/Downloads/names.txt"
while IFS=, read -ra names; do
    printf "%s\n" "${names[@]}"

    for ((i=0; i < ${#fields[@]}; i++)); do
        srvnm=`echo ${hostname:0:3} | tr [a-z] [A-Z]`
        curdtm=$(date)
        subject= "Hello"
        echo "${fields[i]}" |mailx -s "$subject $curdtm" -a "$logpathfile" -r $srvnm $eml01
        done   
    done < "$file"
```

I am looking to get the results in a single email, for now I get 5 separate emails.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Re *"I am a simple program"*:  there might be a [Loebner Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loebner_Prize) in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the mailx command outside of the loop.

```
file="/home/rkelly/Downloads/names.txt"
srvnm=`echo ${hostname:0:3} | tr [a-z] [A-Z]`
curdtm=$(date)
subject="Hello"
content=""
while IFS=, read -ra names; do
    printf "%s\n" "${names[@]}"
    for ((i=0; i < ${#fields[@]}; i++)); do
        content=$content'\n'${fields[i]}
    done   
done < "$file"
mailx -s "$subject $curdtm" -a "$logpathfile" -r $srvnm $eml01 $content
```